# Batch file to delete sub folder if exist and else batch file should create new folders?

Tags: batch-file

i need a  Batch file to delete Sub folder in a folder if exist  else batch file should  create new sub folders in Mainfolder?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is too easy but you have not shown what you have already tried that is not working. Simply edit your answer with what you have tried and then others or myself should be able to help you get this resolved easily. It should be as simple as `IF EXIST "%SubFolderPath%" RD /Q "%SubFolderPath%"` and `IF NOT EXIST "%SubFolderPath%" MD "%SubFolderPath%"` really with maybe a tweak or two depending on your specifics.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set SF=PathToSubFolder
if not "%~1"=="" set SF=%~1

if exist "%SF%" (
    ECHO Sub folder found. Deleting . . . 
    RD /S /Q "%SF%"
) else (
    ECHO Sub folder not found. Creating . . .
    MKDIR "%SF%"
)
ECHO Completed.
```

If you save that as `CheckSub.bat` you can either edit the file to set the subdirectory, or you can run it from another batch file or command prompt window with the command: `call CheckSub.bat "C:\Path\To\Sub\Folder"` (if you call it that way it overwrites whatever you set in the file